# R: When concatenating CSV files and getting the mean for 1 variable I get correct answer for 1 file but incorrect for sequence

Tags: r, csv, concatenation, mean, na

link for a zip of the CSV files I am using:

https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip

code:

```
getpollutant <- function(id=1:332, directory, pollutant) {
    data<-NULL
    for (i in 1:length(id)) {
            data[[i]]<- c(paste(directory, "/",formatC(id[i], width=3, flag=0),".csv",sep=""))     
    }
    df<-NULL
    for (d in 1:length(data)) { df[[d]]<-c(read.csv(data[d]))
    }
    m<-NULL
    for (i in  1:length(df)) {
            if (pollutant=="nitrate"){
                    m<-mean(df[[i]]$nitrate, na.rm=T)
            }
            if (pollutant=="sulfate"){
                    m<-mean(df[[i]]$sulfate, na.rm=T)
            }


    }
    m
```

}

When I use getpollutant to calculate 1 file's pollutant mean for nitrate or sulfate I get the correct answer but for some reason when I try to enter a sequence of files the mean I get is too high, I have a feeling it has to do with the way NA values are being handled but I couldn't find a way to include NA values in the mean calculation

Comment: if you wish NA values to be included first write a new data frame where you replace NA values with 0, e.g. `df$nitrate[is.na(df$nitrate)] <- 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last for loop, you keep reassinging the file mean to `m`. This means that `m` will always have the mean of the last file you have read. You have made no effort to combine data across files. If you want, you could collect a vector of all the data points first, then take a mean at the end something like

```
#before loop
v <- numeric()
#in loop
v <- c(v, df[[i]]$sulfate)
#after loop
mean(v, na.rm=T)
```

Or you could store the sums and lengths to calculate the mean yourself.

```
#before loop
total<-0; N<-0;
#in loop
total <- total + sum(df[[i]]$sulfate, na.rm=T)
N <- N + sum(!is.na(df[[i]]$sulfate))
#after loop
total/N
```

Comment: Thanks!, I'm just a beginner, trying to get used to R after working in Python for a long time. This was very helpful!